# virtualhost problem

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

I used to add virtual hosts no problem in `httpd.conf`.

Now with splitting up vhosts into separate files something's wrong: I could only get the first of the vhosts in sites-enabled to appear. Eventually I found a solution I don't like, that works on my local linux boxes, but not on my Amazon AWS Ubuntu server. (the reason I don't like it is that I'd like to do it by making separate files, like the guides say to do it, minimizing potential problems if something is typed wrong, and I want it to work both local and remote.)

Here's what I did that ended up working locally: I added the following to the end of the `apache2.conf` file (copied idea from http://www.techstaty.com):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example1
DocumentRoot /var/www/example1
ErrorLog /var/www/logs/error_log
CustomLog /var/www/logs/custom common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName exampletwo
DocumentRoot /var/www/exampletwo
ErrorLog /var/www/logs/error_log
CustomLog /var/www/logs/custom common
</VirtualHost>
```

updating `/etc/hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost example1 exampletwo
```

works fine.

The reason I don't like it is that I don't understand why not putting them in separate files in `sites-available`, then `a2ensite example1`, ditto for `exampletwo`, and `a2dissite default`, then restarting the server, doesn't make my two virtual hosts work. I read that if you always get the first alphabetical virtual server no matter which host you request, the server is confused.

So how do I test to figure out what's wrong? Why does it work on my two local ubuntu boxes (12.10 & 12.04), but not on the Amazon AWS Ubuntu 12.04 instance?

`apache2ctl configtest` says: `Syntax OK`. and restarting `apache2ctl graceful` shows no errors. I've also checked the access & error logs w/o gaining insight.

I also tried: `a2enmod vhosts_alias` but that made no difference. (I figure my problem is prior to someone trying: www.ex... rather than: example1.)

Comment: You could try contacting Amazon's customer service as this might be related to their configuration of the server.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Rackspace.
To set up two domains as separate virtual hosts. I modified the virtual hosts attribute to

```
<VirtualHost example1:80>
ServerName example1
DocumentRoot /var/www/example1
ErrorLog /var/www/logs/error_log
CustomLog /var/www/logs/custom common
</VirtualHost>
```

Similarly, I edited the second virtual host to exampletwo:80

If this doesn't work, you can also try adding NameVirtualHosts in ports.conf.